# Windows Phone 7 Web Browser Only Load HTML

Tags: windows-phone-7, download, browser

Hi i'm using the webbrowser control to download a html webpage. I only need the code, however the webbrowser is also downloading all the extra css/javascript/images linked to from the webpage, which is using up time and bandwidth. So is there a way to make the web browser only download the webpage and nothing else? I have to use this webbrowser because it's logged in to the site, so unfortunately a webclient would not work.

Thanks,
ng93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is it logged into the site? Could you use GetCookies() API on the browser control and add that to the HttpWebRequest?